# Use SSRS to move child rows to repeating columns for exporting?

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I'm trying to take an ugly SQL output and use SSRS to make it suitable for export to a mail house.

What would be the right approach to group data from this:

| order_no | type | name | item | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | header | sally | *NULL* | *NULL* |
| 1 | data | *NULL* | book | 12.50 |
| 1 | data | *NULL* | dvd | 39.00 |
| 2 | header | bob | NULL | NULL |
| 2 | data | *NULL* | shirt | 50.00 |
| 2 | data | *NULL* | shorts | 65.00 |

Into this?

| order_no | type | name | item_1 | price_1 | item_2 | price_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | header | sally | book | 12.50 | dvd | 39.00 |
| 2 | header | bob | shirt | 50.00 | shorts | 65.00 |

Should this be a Matrix? I'm having trouble getting making progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a much cleaner way of doing this but this is the approach I took...

First I replicated your sample data

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(order_no int, [type] varchar(20), [name] varchar(20),  [item] varchar(20), price decimal (10,2))
INSERT INTO @t VALUES
(1,'header',    'sally' , NULL,     NULL ),
(1,'data',      NULL    , 'book',   12.50),
(1,'data',      NULL    , 'dvd',    39.00),
(2,'header',    'bob'   , NULL,     NULL ),
(2,'data',      NULL    , 'shirt',  50.00),
(2,'data',      NULL    , 'shorts', 65.00)

;
WITH o (order_no, [type], [name], [item], [price], [ItemNumber]) AS 
    (
        SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY order_no ORDER BY item) AS ItemNumber FROM @t WHERE [type] != 'header'
    )

SELECT 
        h.order_no, h.[type], h.name
        , d.ItemNumber, d.ItemCaption, d.ItemValue
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT order_no, [Type], [name] FROM @t WHERE [type] = 'header') h 
    JOIN 
        (
        SELECT order_no, ItemNumber, 'Item_' + CAST(ItemNumber as varchar(10)) as ItemCaption, Item as ItemValue from o
        UNION
        SELECT order_no, ItemNumber, 'Price_' + CAST(ItemNumber as varchar(10)) as ItemCaption, CAST(Price as varchar(20)) as ItemValue from o
        ) d ON h.order_no = d.order_no
```

I created a CTE just to clean up the query a little and included an row_number for each item, we'll use this to created column captions which we can use in the matrix.

This gives us the following output

[image]

We now have everything in place for a simple matrix.

**Note:** As we had to convert everything to strings, the prices are no longer numbers so bear this in mind if you plan on doing anything else with the data later - they would have to be converted back

So, create a new report, add a new dataset and use the above query as the dataset query.

Add a matrix control, drag `order_no` to the row placeholder, `ItemCaption` to the column placeholder and `ItemValue` to the data placeholder.

Next, right-click the `order_no` column and choose "insert column - inside group right", the set new column value to your `type` field. Repeat for the `header` field.

Your design will look like this.

[image]

**Finally** In the column group sort properties, sort by `ItemNumber` then `ItemCaption`

[image]

The final report looks like this...

[image]

Comment: Hi Alan, thank you so much for the detailed analysis and screenshots! I have marked this as Answered :)